# How to use asyncio in Pythonista3?

Tags: python, pythonista

I tried to use asyncio in Pythonista3 (iPhone/iPad App) and got errors...

(Pythonista3: Python 3.6.1)

I used [this movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3RyxVOLjz8) as a reference and wrote a code;

```
import asyncio
import random

@asyncio.coroutine
asyncio def myCoroutine(id):
    process_time = random.randint(1, 5)
    await asyncio.sleep(process_time)
    print('Coroutine: {}. has successfully completed after {} seconds'.format(id, process_time))

@asyncio.coroutine
async def main():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(10):
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(myCoroutine(i)))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

 
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Error message is:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited
```

I replaced (async def) > (def), but another error occurred:

```
await asyncio.sleep(process_time)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Additionally, I removed (@asyncio.coroutine), but another error occurred:

```
raise TypeError('A Future or coroutine is required')
```

Do you have any solutions?

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the typo `asyncio def` -> `async def` on line 5 and remove the decorators (`@asyncio.coroutine`), and the code works.

I tested this on Pythonista, but there is nothing specific to Pythonista as an environment here.